# Pandas handling Dictionary inside Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My code:

```
d = [{"cityId": 111, "regionId": 111, 'data':[{'code': 'ABC', 'date': '2023-11-11 02:00', 'value': 300}, {'code': 'ABC', 'date': '2023-11-12 02:00', 'value': 300}]},
     {"cityId": 211, "regionId": 211, 'data':[{'code': 'XYZ', 'date': '2023-11-11 02:00', 'value': 300}, {'code': 'XYZ', 'date': '2023-11-12 02:00', 'value': 300}]}]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
new_df = df.explode('data')['data']
new_df = json_normalize(new_df)
```

My current output:

```
   cityId  regionId                                               data
0     111       111  [{'code': 'ABC', 'date': '2023-11-11 02:00', '...
1     211       211  [{'code': 'XYZ', 'date': '2023-11-11 02:00', '...
  code              date  value
0  ABC  2023-11-11 02:00    300
1  ABC  2023-11-12 02:00    300
2  XYZ  2023-11-11 02:00    300
3  XYZ  2023-11-12 02:00    300
```

My desired output:

```
  code              date  value cityId  regionId
0  ABC  2023-11-11 02:00    300  111       111
1  ABC  2023-11-12 02:00    300  111       111
2  XYZ  2023-11-11 02:00    300  211       211
3  XYZ  2023-11-12 02:00    300  211       211
```

I suppose I should do join or merge, but when I tried those I multiply the columns.
I have done this with the loop but I am asked to make my cord shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), you can pass the `meta` parameter to add the 2 *missing* columns :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(d, "data", meta=["cityId", "regionId"])
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  code              date  value cityId regionId
0  ABC  2023-11-11 02:00    300    111      111
1  ABC  2023-11-12 02:00    300    111      111
2  XYZ  2023-11-11 02:00    300    211      211
3  XYZ  2023-11-12 02:00    300    211      211

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved whole problem in one line of code :) !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
d = [
    {
        "cityId": 111,
        "regionId": 111,
        "data": [
            {"code": "ABC", "date": "2023-11-11 02:00", "value": 300},
            {"code": "ABC", "date": "2023-11-12 02:00", "value": 300},
        ],
    },
    {
        "cityId": 211,
        "regionId": 211,
        "data": [
            {"code": "XYZ", "date": "2023-11-11 02:00", "value": 300},
            {"code": "XYZ", "date": "2023-11-12 02:00", "value": 300},
        ],
    },
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.explode("data")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("data").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   cityId  regionId code              date  value
0     111       111  ABC  2023-11-11 02:00    300
1     111       111  ABC  2023-11-12 02:00    300
2     211       211  XYZ  2023-11-11 02:00    300
3     211       211  XYZ  2023-11-12 02:00    300
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I was missing this reset_index which was key